# Why was Tacotron trained on <1000h of speech data?

Tags: speech-synthesis

Tacotron TTS models (e.g. [Tacotron 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05884.pdf) and [Parallel Tacotron 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.14574.pdf)) were trained on 25h and 405h of speech data respectively. By comparison, [more recent TTS](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.15687) systems are trained on >50,000h of speech data. Why were Tacotron models trained on such a relatively small volume of data?

Comment: Could the answer just be when they were trained? Bigger models and input data sets require more resources. So this may follow a pattern analogous to Moore's law.